# can't convert string to datetime object in a json, without pandas?

Tags: python, datetime

i have a json where the time is located in the field 'createdAt'.
`'createdAt': '2020-10-17T02:56:51+0900'`

I want to parse the time (which is a string) and convert it into a datetime object, but I'm not why my code isn't picking up on the specified datetime format and is returning all my createdAt times with 0.

```
for line in data:
    try:
        date_time_str = line['createdAt']
        date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(f'{str(date_time_str)}', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
        line['createdAt'] = date_time_obj
    except ValueError:
        line['createdAt'] = 0
```

note: not allowed to use dateutil

Comment: What is the error you get / what doesn't work as expected? The strptime format looks perfectly fine. Also, simply feeding `date_time_str` into strptime should do, no need for the f-string + the str().

Comment: Why can' t you use `dateutil`? Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: @baduker: it's not needed anyway as I see it, so I'd not care about that ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes i get 'createdAt': 0 for all of the times in my json, so for some reason my code is going straight to the except condition

Comment: ok so what is `data`?

Comment: @MrFuppes a json file with a few lines, but values for 'createdAt' is the only thing i'm trying to change

Comment: I mean what *type* is data? I understand your input is a json (file), but in your code, `data` is used as if it was a list of dictionaries - which I think is the issue here...

Comment: @MrFuppes {"title": "First title", "createdAt": "2020-10-19T02:56:51+0000", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"}, where data contains 10 similar objects as the line provided. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this?

```
from datetime import datetime

data = [
    {"title": "First title", "createdAt": "2020-10-19T02:56:51+0000", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"},
    {"title": "Second title", "createdAt": "2020-10-19T02:56:51+0000", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"},
    {"title": "Third title", "createdAt": "2020-10-19T02:56:51+0000", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"},
]

for item in data:
    try:
        item['createdAt'] = datetime.strptime(item['createdAt'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    except ValueError:
        item['createdAt'] = ""

print(data)
print(data[0]['createdAt'])
```

Which gives you:

```
[{'title': 'First title', 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 19, 2, 56, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'text': 'Some post content', 'author': 'ninja'}, {'title': 'Second title', 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 19, 2, 56, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'text': 'Some post content', 'author': 'ninja'}, {'title': 'Third title', 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 19, 2, 56, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'text': 'Some post content', 'author': 'ninja'}]
2020-10-19 02:56:51+00:00
```

Fun fact:

> No `dateutil` used!

Comment: this code gives me TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int. when i modify my code to line['createdAt'] = datetime.strptime(str(line['createdAt']), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"), i get the same error (e.g. where all 'createdAt' fields = 0)

Comment: What's `data` then? Show us an example of an object you work with.

Comment: data = {"title": "First title", "createdAt": "2020-10-19T02:56:51+0000", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"} * 10

Comment: What's `* 10`? Does that mean you have ten such objects or a list of ten objects like the one showed?

Comment: sorry - yeah, like 10 json objects as the example provided